# Conseguir pegar todos os dados do INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Meu problema é que estou fazendo uma consulta porém não estou conseguindo listar todos os dados na tabela.

```
SELECT * FROM suporte s
INNER JOIN login l ON l.cliente_id = s.cliente_id
INNER JOIN radius_acct r ON r.USERNAME = l.user
WHERE s.CLOSEDATA = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND r.ACCTSTOPTIME = '00-00-0000 00:00:00' limit 50;
```

Quando coloco `<td ><?php echo $linha['opendata']; ?></td>` funciona normalmente,  porém os dados que ficam a direita na consulta não são exibidos. Ex: `<td class="cliente1"><?php echo $linha['acctstarttime']; ?></td>`
me retorna

> Notice: Undefined index: acctstarttime in D:\www\teste\index.php on
>   line 76.

Alguém sabe oque pode estar causando esse problema ?

Comment: não to conseguindo entender bem. como assim "direita da consulta"? posta o código (pelo menos da linha 70 até a 76 que é onde dá o erro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta isto,

```
SELECT suporte.*, login.*, radius_acct.* FROM suporte
INNER JOIN login ON login.cliente_id = suporte.cliente_id
INNER JOIN radius_acct ON radius_acct.USERNAME = login.user
WHERE suporte.CLOSEDATA = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND radius_acct.ACCTSTOPTIME = '00-00-0000 00:00:00' limit 50;
```

Desta maneira estamos a selecionar tudo das três tabelas

Comment: Tentei porém apareceu Erro: 1054
Descrição: Unknown column 's.CLOSEDATA' in 'where clause'

Comment: @LeoneHenrique queres selecionar todos os dados da tabela de login e da tabela de suporte certo?

Comment: certo, funcionou a consulta, dentro do mysql me monstra todas as coluna que preciso porém ainda não consigo pegar os dados de algumas colunas. As primeiras coluna funcionam normalmente porém as ultimas colunas é me retornado o error
 Notice: Undefined index: acctstarttime in D:\www\teste\index.php on line 73

Comment: Vê lá agora @LeoneHenrique, com essa edição que fiz

Comment: ainda continua o mesmo error, acho que pode ser alguma limitação do INNER JOIN.

Comment: Tens a certeza que o nome da coluna está bem escrito? tentaste como está em cima @LeoneHenrique? É o ACCTSTOPTIME da tabela radius_acct certo?

Comment: sim o nome esta certo, ja até tentei com outras colunas, eu consigo pega os dados da tabela login e suporte, porém a tabela radius_acct não vai de jeito nenhum.

Comment: @LeoneHenrique, tentaste como tenho em cima? É estranho porque eu estou a selecionar tudo das três tabelas

Comment: Sim tentei exatamente como me passou,, ja tentei com a coluna acctstarttime, acctstoptime e username que estão em radius_acct e não vai, se eu colocar a coluna user que esta na tabela login porém tem o mesmo conteúdo de username que esta em radius_acct funciona normalmente.
OBS: A consulta esta funcionando, o problema é pegar os dados.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta a meneira com estás a extrair e tentar exibir os dados no PHP @LeoneHenrique

Comment: consegui, venho até te pedir desculpa pois o problema éra realmente o nome, por algum motivo apenas nessa tabela eu tenho que colocar exatamente AcctStartTime, ou seja se colocar acctstarttime ou ACCTSTATTIME como fiz nas outras tabelas não funciona.

Comment: hehe @LeoneHenrique, sem problema se a resposta ajudou deves aceita-la, à esquerda da resposta por baixo das setas cima/baixo. Bem-vindo ao SO PT